# simple search box in django

Tags: django, search

I'm trying to create a very simple search function which would filter by a key word given into search form.

html search form:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ request.get.q }}">
  <input type="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder=„search">
  <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get(q)
    if query:
        results = Sklep.objects.filter(miasto=query)
        if results.count():
            context_dict['results'] = results
        else:
            context_dict['no_results'] = query
    return render(request, "apka/lista.html", context_dict)
```

div to display results:

```
<div>
{% if no_results %}
    No results returned for <q>{{ no_results }}</q>
{% else %}
    {% for result in results %}
        {{ result.miasto }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

and finally models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Sklep(models.Model):
    miasto = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
    )
    nazwa = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
    )
    adres = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.miasto +", "+ self.nazwa+", "+self.adres`
```

Template seems to not show any results, neither "no results..." nor any filtered entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you check if this function is executed , and do a print inside             
        if query: print("query ")  and check if action="{{ request.get.q }}"  URL is proper

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work was query = request.GET.get(q) without "". No q was acquired and as a result loop wasn't executed.

The answer is actually replacing `query = request.GET.get(q)` with `query = request.GET.get('q')`